# ChartJS - How to choose the visible datalabels

Tags: charts, chart.js

I would like to ask how to choose which data labels should be visible on the line chart? It looks like on the screen[image]

But it's not nice. I would like to have visible only every second the label. I thought to check how many labels there are. Then if more than X choose only some, but maybe there is something easier.

Here is the code from labels:

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                align: 'top',
                color: '#000000',
                font: {
                    weight: 'bold',
                    size: '16'
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Level'
        }
      }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [`formatter`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#formatting) that returns the `value` or an empty `string` in case you want to skip the data label.

The following formatter for example makes sure, only every second data label appears on your chart.

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      ...
      formatter: (value, context) => context.dataIndex % 2 == 0 ? value : ''
    }
    ...
```

This can be extended with a check for the total number of values. The following formatter returns every `value` as long as the total number of values is lower than `100`. Otherwise, it only returns every second `value`.

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      ...
      formatter: (value, context) =>  context.chart.data.datasets[0].data.length < 100 || context.dataIndex % 2 == 0 ? value : ''
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check it, but looks nice.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I would like to ask how did you find the answer? In documentation? I tried to find it but did not find.

Comment: @Mariusz Adamczewski: I consulted `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` documentation and expected to find a `filter` function. Finally, however, I just found the `formatter` function and played around with it until I got the expected result.